# how to use yii array

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

guys i am using yii2 advance i have got little problem in it i have got 2 table where i have to relation between this two

```
       ---------------------               -----------------
       |      roleedu      |               |     bio       |
       |-------------------|               |---------------|
       | Roleedu_id        |               | bio_id        |
       | Roleedu_position  |               | Roleedu_id    |
       ---------------------               -----------------
               |                                    |
               |                                    |
               |                                    |
           roleedu                                 bio
-----------------------------------    -------------|---------------
|  Roleedu_id  | Roleedu_position |    |   bio_id   | Roleedu_id   |
-----------------------------------    -------------|---------------
|       1      |      cat         |    |      1     |    2,3       |
|       2      |      bat         |    |      2     |    1,2,3     |
|       3      |      ox          |    |      3     |    4,3       |
|       4      |      crow        |    |      4     |    4,3,2     |
-----------------------------------    -----------------------------
```

and my "bio" model is

```
public function getRoleedu(){
    return $this->hasOne(Roleedu::className(), ['Roleedu_id' => 'Roleedu_id']);
}
public function getRole(){
    return $this->roleedu->Roleedu_position;
}
```

and my "roleedu" model is

```
public function getBios(){
    return $this->hasMany(Bio::className(), ['Roleedu_id' => 'Roleedu_id']);
}
```

my view

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'bio_id',
        'Role',
    ],
]) ?>
```

when i view it show like this

```
bio_id = 4
Role = crow
```

but i would like to show like this ex

```
bio_id = 4
Role  = crow,ox,bat
```

how can it be possible?? any suggestion ?
thank you in advance guys ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column Roleedu_id from the bio table has to die a horrible death. It is a terrible way to design a DB and that is why you have problems. You actually have absolutely no known relation between the tables.

If you really insist on using such a terrible design your role function should be

```
public function getRole(){
     return implode(',', ArrayHelper::map(Roleedu::find()->where('Roleedu_id IN ('.$this->Roleedu_id.')')->asArray()->all(), 'Roleedu_position', 'Roleedu_position'));
}
```

The code is not tested but it should be reasonably close to what you want.
Delete any other relation that you have design and you have no relations.

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i use it its says PHP Parse Error – yii\base\ErrorException syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: I believe I forgot a ) at the end. Try it again.